# Asp.Net MVC3, returning success JsonResult

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to return JSON data that contain success value (true or false) also, it need to have result message too.

so I using Dictionary to contain data but when it return to Jason data, it contain ""(Quot).

```
JsonResult = new Dictionary<string, string>();
JsonResult.Add("Success", "False");
JsonResult.Add("Message", "Error Message");
return Json(JsonResult);
```

it returns,

```
{"Success":"False","Message":"Error Message"}
```

but I need,

```
{Success:False,Message:"Error Message"} //with out "" (Quot)
```

Anybody know about this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
{"Success":"False","Message":"Error Message"}
```

**is valid JSON**.  You can check it [here](http://jsonlint.com/). in jsonlint.com

You don't even need a Dictionary to return that JSON. You can simply use an anonymous variable like this:

```
public ActionResult YourActionMethodName()
{
   var result=new { Success="False", Message="Error Message"};
   return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

to Access this data from your client, you can do this.

```
$(function(){
   $.getJSON('YourController/YourActionMethodName', function(data) {
      alert(data.Success);
      alert(data.Message);
   });
});
```

Comment: +1 I came to write this, although I wouldn't have used a variable, but that's just my preference :)

Comment: @mattytommo: I love anonymous types in C# in scenarios like this

Comment: The Success key still has to be in quotes, and your code does that. Unless the OP has a typo...he's asking for invalid JSON. Your code returns {"Success":"False","Message":"Error Message"}

Comment: @BZink: You are correct. That OP's JSON is valid. should be a problem in his client script. I updated my answer to mention that.

Comment: contentType: 'application/json'; also woriking fine