# server error always calls ajax success callback jQuery from an MVC HttpPost

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

This is my javascript code and my controller looks like this
but whenever there is an error or Exception it always goes to success callback What am i missing here

### Javascript

```
var options = { 
    iframe: true,
    type: 'post',
    url: "api/Registration/Register",
    data: { "data": jsonData },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) 
    {                 
        if (statusText == 'success') { 
        }
        else { //code == 'FAIL'
        }
    },
    error: function (response, status, err) {
    }};

    $('#registration').ajaxSubmit(options);


[HttpPost]
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Register()
{
    //create task object and read server data
    try
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(assistedRegResponse.Response))
        };
        return response;
     }
     catch (Exception ex){ throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex));}           
     return task;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code you have posted you are always setting the status code to ok.  From here [Asp.Net MVC3, returning success JsonResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608198/asp-net-mvc3-returning-success-jsonresult) you should set the result according to the result on the controller and return it.

```
success: function(result){
    if(result.Success){
        //code for success
    }else{
        alert(result.Error);
    }
}
```

something like that.  Hope this helps

Comment: thanks Matt, but I am using HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError in catck block where i am throwing an error