# How to fix jsonresult, which didn't populate in the View but have data in controller

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

im new in coding using javascrip,json and mvc. I have some question hope you can help me. I have codes when i use to debug in controller it have data but when it returning to view using json result it will not interface to table.

Controller/C# code:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult getAccountability()
    {
        var data = db.cct_custodials.Where(w => w.EmployeeNo == UserCurrentRole.UserID).OrderBy(o => o.DateCreated).ToList();
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer { MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue };
        var result = new ContentResult
        {
            Content = serializer.Serialize(data),
            ContentType = "application/json"
        };
        return result;
    }
```

View/HTML code:

```
function attachCustodial() {
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function () {
            $.blockUI({ baseZ: 2000 });
        },
        cache: true,
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Accountability/getAccountability',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
            var oTable = $('#dtFinalTransfer').dataTable();
            oTable.fnDestroy();

            oTable.dataTable({
                "bSortClasses": false,
                "bSort": false,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bPaginate": true,
                "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
                "iDisplayLength": 2000,
                "aaData": json.result,
                "aoColumns": [
                    {
                        "mData": null,
                        "sClass": "ctr valign",
                        "sWidth": "5%"
                    },
                    {
                        "mData": "ProjectName",
                        "sClass": "ctr valign",
                        "sWidth": "15%"
                    },
                    {
                        "mData": "ReferenceNo",
                        "sClass": "ctr valign",
                        "sWidth": "15%"
                    },
                    {
                        "mData": "CustodialNo",
                        "sClass": "ctr valign",
                        "sWidth": "15%"
                    },
                    {
                        "mData": "IssuedBy",
                        "sClass": "ctr valign",
                        "sWidth": "20%"
                    },
                    {
                        "mData": "Name",
                        "sClass": "ctr valign",
                        "sWidth": "20%"
                    },
                    {
                        "mData": null,
                        "sWidth": "10%",
                        "bSearchable": false,
                        "sClass": "ctr valign",
                        "sDefaultContent": '<a class="pointer" onclick="viewCustodial(this)">&nbsp;View&nbsp;</a>',
                    }
                ]
            });
            tableCounter(oTable);
            $.unblockUI();
        },
        error: function (e) { $.unblockUI(); checkmsg('Please contact your system admininistrator' + e.responseText) }
    });
}
```

but when using this code..I encounter error *"Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer.

> The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength
>   property."

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult getAccountability()
        {

            //var data = db.cct_custodials.Where(w => w.EmployeeNo == UserCurrentRole.UserID && w.ReferenceNo == "JAZZ-2017-B0009").OrderBy(o => o.DateCreated).ToList(); for sample
            var data = db.cct_custodials.Where(w => w.EmployeeNo == UserCurrentRole.UserID).OrderBy(o => o.DateCreated).ToList();
              return Json(new { result = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
       }
```

expect output will to populate the table with hundred thousand or millions of records.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608198/asp-net-mvc3-returning-success-jsonresult). Also, I suggest using GET to such requests where you’re just (indeed!) getting data from a repository of any sort.

Comment: @DavideVitali I used your code but when my query getting big(10k++) records then encounter error. but when my query select like 100 below records the table will populate

Comment: Well, I guess the problem is in the data

Comment: if possible then use server side pagination get only 10 or 20 data at time and on next page take another one.

Answer (score 0):

Here issue is your json string length is exceeds to default because as you convey

> expect output will to populate the table with hundred thousand or
>   millions of records.

You can set the MaxJsonLength property in web.config file:

```
<configuration> 
  <system.web.extensions>
   <scripting>
       <webServices>
           <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="..."/>
       </webServices>
   </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

set `maxJsonLength` and **default** `maxJsonLength` is **102400** so set this value.

**Suggestion:** If possible then used server side pagination because getting millions of records from server is not feasible. get only 10 to 20 records at a time and get another records on next page.